# Update a chromedriver in selenium library

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, netbeans, selenium-chromedriver

Few days ago, I've met a problem working on java programs using selenium and chromedriver (Chrome doesn't even start last time). Tried to update my Chromedriver library to **2.25**, but when I add current version to libraries they become @Deprecated. I can not remove jar with previous version because of another classes. How could I force file to read Class from newer version (their package's name are the same)? I'm using NetBeans.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it wasn't about selenium library, but chromedriver.exe. Instead of using default chromderiver.exe download new one (2.25) and before driver declaration set:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path\to\chromedriver.exe");
```

Now it works properly